# $\ell_1$ error minimization on $\ell_\infty$ ball

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, normed-spaces

Given vector $y \in \mathbb R^n$ and invertible matrix $B \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{x \in \mathbb R^n}{\text{minimize}} & \lVert y - B x \rVert_1\\ \text{subject to} & \lVert x\rVert_\infty\le 1\end{array}$$

This could be tackled with linear programming. However, I wonder, is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You can use, for instance, ADMM (among others).

Comment: You may want to take a look at Candès & Romberg's [$\ell_1$-magic: recovery of sparse signals via convex programming](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/software/l1magic/downloads/l1magic.pdf) (2005).

Answer (score 0):

A possibility (HINT):

You can formulate your problem as
\begin{align}
&\min_x         & & \underbrace{\left\|y-z \right\|_1}_{:=g(z)} + \underbrace{\delta_{C}(x)}_{:=f(x)} \\
& \mathrm{s.t.} & &Bx = z,
\end{align}
where the set $C = \left\{  x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \left\| x \right\|_{\infty} \leq 1 \right\}$.

Apply ADMM algorithm (not sure if it will be more efficient than LP)...